# Data collection with Android via USB

Tags: android, usb, serial-port

What would be the best way to access the USB as a serial port on an Android device (`HTC Magic`)?

I am thinking about an OBD-II interface.  Can I do this on a standard phone or more likely will I need a modified firmware?

Comment: USB host mode on nexus 1 : [Have a look at this link](http://www.engadget.com/2010/06/04/nexus-one-gets-usb-host-driver-from-a-dude-with-an-oscilloscope/)

Answer (score 4):

According to [this post](http://laforge.gnumonks.org/weblog/2009/11/04/#20091104-android_mythbusters), Matt Porter presented a review of Android at the Embedded Linux Conference Europe.  I mention this mostly because of the example used to describe the current state of Android.

> "Just one more practical example: You cannot even plug a USB drive to an android system, since /dev/sd* is not an expected device name in their hardcoded hotplug management.
>
> Executive summary: Android is a screwed, hard-coded, non-portable abomination."

I'm sure someone's working on it, but I'm afraid for now you're out of luck unless you're willing to go low-level and edit the OS.

Answer (score 3):

PSFreedom (project to jailbrack Playstation 3) has [list of controllers which support usb host mode](http://psfreedom.com/wiki/ControllerList) which then translate to [supported Android devices](http://psfreedom.com/wiki/Device_compatibility_list).

My own expirience is that usb host works on HTC Dream/G1 without problems.

For OBD-II I would suggest [bluetooth ODB-II dongle](http://www.dealextreme.com/details.dx/sku.16921) which side-stepps problem with usb host adapter.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the USB chip in your particular phone, it may be possible to rebuild the kernel to support USB Host mode or USB On-The-Go (Host + Gadget modes) instead of the normal USB Gadget mode.  I've found some people speculating that it [could be possible on the HTC Dream](http://android-dls.com/wiki/index.php?title=G1_USB_Host).  Assuming you could reconfigure the USB port in Host mode a USB to serial, ODB-II, or CAN should be doable.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell Android is Linux of some sort, to have USB device which would apear as serial port, you should write a driver for that device. I don't know much about OBD-II interface but i am guesing they use some sort of USB driver for windows, same is for android, not mentioning the application to handle the driver.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the current Android devices can act as a USB host only as a USB device when attached to a host.  So using the USB port as a serial port is not likely.

Answer (score 0):

Get a hostmode kernel for your device and you can use python for android and the pyserial library to talk to the serial over USB. I did this with Huawei Ideos U8150 ([here is the post](http://karibe.co.ke/2012/07/usb-host-mode-serial-on-u8150-android-pyserial/)) for a loopback test.